# Selenium importing google profile DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, profile

The error I am receiving is:

```
C:\Users\CharlieWait\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_90388\1267197158.py:9: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  w = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\CharlieWait\\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
```

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\CharlieWait\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data") #Path to your chrome profile
w = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\CharlieWait\\chromedriver.exe", options=options)

Does anyone know how can I resolve this issue? I've tried passing as a service but that seem not to resolve the problem.
```

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager


ffOptions = Options()

ffOptions.add_argument("-profile")
ffOptions.add_argument("C:\\Users\\CharlieWait\AppData\\Local\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\ojcjbj1l.default-release")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install()),options=ffOptions)

driver.get("http://www.google.com")

Answer (score 0):

You should use Service.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

w = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service("C:\\Users\\CharlieWait\\chromedriver.exe"), options=options)
```

Comment: Hi so this wouldnt work for me so i have moved to firefox and yet it still refuses to load profile

Comment: The error in your question is related to executable_path deprecation warning, that's why I answered, is it resolved now? Is Chrome browser opened?